# c# Regex expression to extract all non-numeric values in brackets

Tags: regex

This is the Regex expression i have built so far `\{([^{]*[^0-9])\}`.

> "This is the sample string {0} {1} {}  {abc} {12abc} {abc123}"

I wish to extract everything within the string that includes brackets and that does not contain only an integer.

> (e.g) '{}' 
>    '{abc}' '{12abc}' '{abc123}'

However the last one which contains numbers at the end is not extracted with the rest.

> {abc123}

How can i extract all values in the string that are in curly brackets and do not contain an Integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"{(?!\d+})[^{}]*}")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YlCQXU/1/) and the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/6XzUtP).

**Pattern details**

- `{` - a `{` char
- `(?!\d+})` - no 1+ digits and then `}` allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^{}]*` - 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.